# Ubuntu partition. To recover files

Tags: partitioning

Linux does not work for me at all right now. Never did on this computer. Toshiba satellite L750 d  .
Nothing I have tried have brought any results. I am stuck in low graphics mode.
And before that, webgl did not work no matter what, except a insanely laggy version in Firefox. After rebooting after I removed Firefox. I got stuck in this mode.

All I want to know is if I can install a partition of Ubuntu, take my files from the buggy version and transfer them. So that I can get windows back, since none of the graphics drivers work for my laptop.

I tried reinstalling graphic driver, desktop, video driver, failsafe x recovery mode, root commands..  I need this pc for work. Would like a windows partition back until I learned a way to make Ubuntu work.

Comment: It worked. I was able to partition the hard drive without any trouble. Found my files. And downloaded them onto the fresh ubuntu partition.

Onwards to remove the old partition.

Comment: I am unable to do so before 10 points :) So unless you upvote me 10 times. I am gonna be in trouble. :o

Comment: Ty ^^, hopefully I am going to be able to work it all out. I like the idea of linux

Answer (score 2):

It worked. I was able to partition the hard drive without any trouble. Found my files. And downloaded them onto the fresh ubuntu partition.

Onwards to remove the old partition!

(Thanks to Lucio for letting me answer my question)